# Exporting to Max from Blender 3D distorts the mesh

Tags: modeling, export

I am trying to export models from Blender 3D to 3D's Max and my model distorts for no reason. Is there any specific settings I need to take care of?

Blender has export options to .3ds, .fbx and .obj (none of them aren't working properly)

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Waqas

[image: Model in Blender 3D]

[image: After exporting from Blender]

Comment: Is the scale applied?

Comment: apply the scale in 3ds max

Comment: You mean I should Apply Scale in Blender before exporting to 3ds max?

Comment: Welcome iowaqas! :) Obj works in any case. Try to do what gandalf3 mentioned. Just a tip: Remove the subsurf in blender and apply a turbosmooth in max, so you have more control.